# invalid file report in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

hello I would like to have a dynamic connection with crystal report but it does not work . The databases of PC A and PC B are the same, just change the connection string

I tried with:

ServerName is SQL server instance

```
report.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(ServerName,DatabaseName,false);
```

**The error that comes out is "invalid report file path"**

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, this is working on PC A, but not on PC B?
Usually, this kind of message means that your report file was not found (the .rpt file), so it's not about database.
Is your file .rpt on common server or on computer?
If on common server, check that the server is mapped the same way on each computer.
If on computers just checked that report files are present on each computer.

Usually when I use Crystal Reports, I add in application a parameter "Reports Folder", and browse the folder to see all .rpt files, and offer opening existing reports, so it avoids this kind of errors.

Comment: each computer has its reports folder and they are loaded as follows report.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Reports\ReportsRecetas.rpt");

Comment: in this line the error occurs "report.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(ServerName,DatabaseName,false);"

Comment: In your post you talk about Computer A and B, it is working on only one of them? Then you wrote that connection string are differents, what is the difference between them?

Comment: If I am working with the visual studio project on both machines, I only modify the instance of sql in the connection string, although this line of code does not work on any machine report.DataSourceConnections [0] .SetConnection (ServerName, DatabaseName, false);

Comment: but the connection string that I use for the rest of the project works on both machines

Comment: the difference between the machines is your instance of SQL, on PC A is SQL2012 and on PC B is SQLSERVER2012

Comment: On my solution, I made it compatible MySQL and SQLSERVER, what I did is add a parameter MySQL/SQLSERVER with ComboBox, then save it in registers, then when I launch my SQL requests, I just check the value, then modify the request regarding with which DataBase I am working, I don't know good SQL/SQLSERVER, but if error is on that line, you may work on it?If you meet only problem with CrystalReports, you can just put a TRY/CATCH, on PCA it will work. on PC B, it will make an catch the error, then execute second request?